# Listening to OS messages in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wndproc

Is there any methods in C# similar to WndProc method to listen to the OS messages.I cant use WndProc because,my class is neither Form nor Inherited from Control(Its DLL)

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            // listen os messages


            // Ueye Message
            case uEye.IS_UEYE_MESSAGE:
                //fetch frame
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: I'm putting this as a comment because I'm not sure, but I think you can use WMI for that. I used it somewhere to listen for removeable USB drives.

Comment: @JonasVan can u give some links how can I use that?(examples)...thank you

Comment: I'll give you the project I was working on.

Comment: What kind of OS messages are you looking for?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2389696/USBFun.7z here you go, I'll leave this up for today at least, longer if I forget to take it down :)

Comment: @Erno actually its message from camera connected through usb port

Answer (score 1):

[WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will do if you want to listen for specific messages.
I once had a project (see comment on question) that listened for removeable USB drives and WMI worked just fine.

You can use interop as well but I find it messy but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach to receiving windows messages in the absence of a visible window is to create a non-visible window to receive messages.

Comment: I created dummy form in my class...but still it says no suitable method to override WndProc...?How you did invisible form and recieved? thank you

Comment: well I always write against the win32 api and call CreateWindow but there's no doubt a .net way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Windows.Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.aspx)

to have access to Win API

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/winforms/thread/b44f06fb-fc4a-4fac-87cd-48b2953ea5fa

It seems to be possible to override WndProc, but I haven't tried it myself!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Form (visible or otherwise), look at `Form.WndProc`.

If not, you could try using [Application.AddMessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx) to add a message filter to monitor Windows messages.

Comment: thing is I have to get it in DLL...not WinForm project

Comment: @Sisya - Yes but if your DLL is called from an application with a message loop (whether WinForms, WPF or unmanaged) Application.AddMessageFilter might work.  Worth a try anyway.